# How to read only used rows in the Excel File

Tags: excel, vb6

I want to read an Excel file in the way that only used rows has to be taken out i.e if the excel file contains 47 rows initially but only 10 rows are filled then that 10 rows data has to be read(Don't want to mention it like A2C7 while reading,need to do it by default) Is it possible to achieve in VB 6.0.Kindly help me to solve this.

```
   Used Range Property has worked for me,but now i found another problem While using this method ,if i add a value in a row after the last used row and remove the value at once and saves the file , it is showing the wrong usedRange value (i.e) it is showing the address of the row where i added and removed the value at once.how to handle this?
```

Comment: Check out the `UsedRange` property of the `Worksheet` object.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand how Excel stores rows. You're over-thinking the problem. The simplest method for you is probably to read the data in the rows until you come to an empty row, then stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reading in the loop till the row is non empty (used). You can get used rows count by the following syntax:

```
<workbookname>.Sheets("<SheetName>").UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

for example

```
Workbook1.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
```